# Using Java 8 stream methods to get the last max value

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Given a list of items with properties, I am trying to get the last item to appear with a maximum value of said property.

For example, for the following list of objects:

```
t  i
A: 3
D: 7 *
F: 4
C: 5
X: 7 *
M: 6
```

I can get one of the Things with the highest `i`:

```
Thing t = items.stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparingLong(Thing::getI))
        .orElse(null);
```

However, this will get me `Thing t = D`. Is there a clean and elegant way of getting the last item, i.e. `X` in this case?

One possible solution is using the `reduce` function. However, the property is calculated on the fly and it would look more like:

```
Thing t = items.stream()
        .reduce((left, right) -> {
            long leftValue = valueFunction.apply(left);
            long rightValue = valueFunction.apply(right);
            return leftValue > rightValue ? left : right;
        })
        .orElse(null);
```

The `valueFunction` now needs to be called nearly twice as often.

Other obvious roundabout solutions are:

1. Store the object in a Tuple with its index
2. Store the object in a Tuple with its computed value
3. Reverse the list beforehand
4. Don't use Streams

Comment: "The valueFunction now needs to be called nearly twice as often." Note that even when using `max`, the `getI` method will be called again and again for every comparison, not just once per element. In your example, it's called 11 times, including 6 times for D. How about you just cache the calculated value directly in the Thing instance?

Comment: @tobias_k I realised that after posting my question. My practical solution was to use a standard for each.

Comment: If your stream goes parallel or async, there can be a complete loss of the idea of "in order". Be sure to think about this and consider if your stream can contain a field or value indicating the order, similar to a tuple of (value, orderIndex) so that the max operation is a simple, parallelizable comparison of the value and orderIndex fields.

Comment: @ErikE if the stream has a defined encounter order, the `reduce` based solution will work in parallel, as long as the reduction function fulfills the associativity constraint. Which is the case here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the equals option (don't return 0 if the compared numbers are equal, return -1 instead) from the comparator (ie. write your own comparator that doesn't include an equals option):

```
Thing t = items.stream()
        .max((a, b) -> a.getI() > b.getI() ? 1 : -1)
        .orElse(null);
```

Comment: I'm not sure that java guarantees the comparator is called "in order", i.e. the later items always is the second argument (thinking about parallel execution). That being said, it makes sense to place a little bit of trust in this implementation detail.

Comment: I've accepted this because it's the most elegant solution and, as far as I can tell, as efficient as a Comparator (which is what I wanted). If I don't want to compute the value every time I have to settle for a for each or a tuple. Thank you.

Comment: I do believe this is not guaranteed to work as you expect the moment that the stream goes parallel/asynch.

Comment: What does this have to do with `equals`? The only trick seems to be to invert the tie-breaking from "a unless b is greater" to "b unless a is greater", which is exactly the same as OP's `reduce` did, but IMHO less readable, as you return `+/-1` instead of the actual object to retain. Also, this, too, will call `getI` more often than necessary (just as often as `reduce`).

Comment: @tobias_k a standard comparator returns +1, 0 or -1, for a being greater than, equal, or less than b. I say 'removing the equals option' meaning my comparator only return +1 or -1, for greater than or not greater than.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. With "remove the equals option" you mean "never return 0". Okay, this could be made _way_ clearer in the answer. Still, this is basically the same as what OP did with `reduce`, calling `getI` just as often.

Comment: The 'clean' solution for this would be a forEach solutuon with a `result` variable to keep the until-then largest value and a `resultI` to keep its `i` value separately (so as not to call `getI()` every time). However, OP asked for a stream solution, and this is it.

Comment: This may happen to work, but still violates the `Comparator` contract, which mandates symmetry. Further, it doesn't solve the problem of invoking `getI()` multiple times per element, hence, is no improvement over a clean `reduce((a, b) -> a.getI() > b.getI()? a: b)`.

Answer (score 5):

Conceptually, you seem to be possibly looking for something like `thenComparing` using the `index` of the elements in the list:

```
Thing t = items.stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparingLong(Thing::getI).thenComparing(items::indexOf))
        .orElse(null);
```

Comment: Assuming: that for two objects if attribute `I` is **equal** that doesn't mean the objects are equal as well. In which case the `indexOf` would return same value always.

Comment: This is nice, but the problem I am trying to solve was actually originally caused by the `equals` method returning true for different objects ;-)

Comment: @Druckles I think then you're trying to solve it in an incorrect way probably.

Comment: You're right. Unfortunately, I didn't write the `equals`.

Comment: Doesn't this give the whole thing O(n²) complexity? Also, would not work for a pure stream, with not backing list (not a requirement, but anyway). Something like Python's `enumerate` would come in handy here.

Comment: @tobias_k My first thought as well here, this will be O(n^2). I think it might be alleviated by the fact that it will only be called with "new" maximum values, but that doesn't count as an argument.

Comment: @Marco13 in the worst case, *all* elements are "new maximum" values in respect to the previous elements, i.e. when the input elements happen to be in ascending order. So O(n²) is the correct time complexity of this solution.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid the multiple applications of valueFunction in your reduce solution, simply explicitly calculate the result and put it in a tuple:

```
Item lastMax = items.stream()
        .map(item -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Item, Long>(item, valueFunction.apply(item)))
        .reduce((l, r) -> l.getValue() > r.getValue() ? l : r )
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Stream is not necessary bad if you do things in two steps :

1) Find the `i` value that has more occurrences in the `Iterable` (as you did)
2) Search the last element for this `i` value by starting from the end of *items*:

```
Thing t =  
  items.stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparingLong(Thing::getI))
        .mapping(firstMaxThing ->  
                   return
                   IntStream.rangeClosed(1, items.size())
                            .mapToObj(i -> items.get(items.size()-i))
                            .filter(item -> item.getI() == firstMaxThing.getI())
                            .findFirst().get(); 
                            // here get() cannot fail as *max()* returned something.
         )
       .orElse(null)
```

Answer (score 1):

> The valueFunction now needs to be called nearly twice as often.

Note that even when using `max`, the `getI` method will be called again and again for every comparison, not just once per element. In your example, it's called 11 times, including 6 times for D, and for longer lists, too, it seems to be called on average twice per element.

How about you just cache the calculated value directly in the `Thing` instance? If this is not possible, you could use an external `Map` and use `calculateIfAbsent` to calculate the value only once for each `Thing` and then use your approach using `reduce`.

```
Map<Thing, Long> cache = new HashMap<>();
Thing x = items.stream()
        .reduce((left, right) -> {
            long leftValue = cache.computeIfAbsent(left, Thing::getI);
            long rightValue = cache.computeIfAbsent(right, Thing::getI);
            return leftValue > rightValue ? left : right;
        })
        .orElse(null);
```

Or a bit cleaner, calculating all the values beforehand:

```
Map<Thing, Long> cache = items.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x, Thing::getI));
Thing x = items.stream()
        .reduce((left, right) -> cache.get(left) > cache.get(right) ? left : right)
        .orElse(null);
```

Comment: BTW, you can easily check how often the comparator callback is called by adding some print statement or incrementing a counter in `getI` or in the callback itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the reduction to get this thing done. If t1 is larger, then only it will keep t1. In all the other cases it will keep t2. If either t2 is larger or t1 and t2 are the same, then it will eventually return t2 adhering to your requirement.

```
Thing t = items.stream().
    reduce((t1, t2) -> t1.getI() > t2.getI() ? t1 : t2)
    .orElse(null);
```

Comment: This is the same solution as I presented in my question.

Comment: @Druckles Technically, the answer you accepted is also the same as your solution, just less obviously so.

Comment: @tobias_k "Less obvious" is everything in programming.

Comment: @Druckles Am I getting you correctly? Your programming goal is to write as obfuscated code as possible?

Comment: @Holger tobias_k was talking about the similarity of two solutions being obvious. He didn't mention readability, understandability or obfuscation.

Comment: @Druckles I don't see any way, how to interpret your sentence "'*Less obvious' is everything in programming*" in a different way than that you like non-obvious things, like the accepted answer, which only makes it *less obvious* that it still does the same as the question's code, including having the same problems, plus adding another one, using a formally incorrect comparator, which makes it *less obvious* why it still happens to do the desired thing. "less obvious" *is* obfuscation. Actually, "is everything" does not only imply that you like it but that it is the most important thing to you.

Comment: You are choosing to take my facetious comment out of context. tobias_k's remark implied that obviousness is not important enough to distinguish between good and bad answers. My remark implied that "obviousness" plays a huge part in programming (which you have kindly demonstrated). And *actually*, "is everything" gives neither positive nor negative weight upon an idea. It simply states its importance.

Comment: But this has become too meta. My original point is that this is a bad answer because it repeats almost identically (albeit without as much boilerplate) a solution in the question and yet ignores the discussion around it (after deleting other anwers).

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation using `reduce` looks good, unless your value-extractor function is costly.

Considering later you may want to reuse the logic for different object types & fields, I would extract the logic itself in separate generic method/methods:

```
public static <T, K, V> Function<T, Map.Entry<K, V>> toEntry(Function<T, K> keyFunc, Function<T, V> valueFunc){
    return t -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(keyFunc.apply(t), valueFunc.apply(t));
}

public static <ITEM, FIELD extends Comparable<FIELD>> Optional<ITEM> maxBy(Function<ITEM, FIELD> extractor, Collection<ITEM> items) {
    return items.stream()
                .map(toEntry(identity(), extractor))
                .max(comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey);
}
```

The code snippets above can be used like this:

```
Thing maxThing =  maxBy(Thing::getField, things).orElse(null);

AnotherThing maxAnotherThing = maxBy(AnotherThing::getAnotherField, anotherThings).orElse(null);
```